# aggregate sql with a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having trouble with this query.

```
SELECT adm_Consultant, count(adm_Consultant) as num
FROM Admission
WHERE  adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '01/01/2014 00:00:00' AND adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '31/12/2014 00:00:00'
AND adm.adm_PriorSurgery = 'Yes'
AND adm.adm_Consultant <> ''
GROUP BY adm_Consultant
```

> ERROR: General error

this works though, but returns the null values as-well

```
SELECT adm_Consultant, count(adm_Consultant) as num
FROM Admission
GROUP BY adm_Consultant
```

I tried the `HAVING` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause, but still it fails.

Please help.

here was my reading material.

`COUNT(expr)`

> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement. The result is a BIGINT value.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: what is the error by the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to create alias adm

```
SELECT adm_Consultant, count(adm_Consultant) as num 
FROM Admission adm
WHERE  adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '01/01/2014 00:00:00' AND 
adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '31/12/2014 00:00:00'
AND adm.adm_PriorSurgery = 'Yes'
AND adm.adm_Consultant <> ''
GROUP BY adm_Consultant
```

Comment: Wow, I feel quit silly now. thanks... such a small thing and you try and look for big things.

Answer (score 2):

Try using ISO standard date formats:

```
SELECT adm_Consultant, count(adm_Consultant) as num
FROM Admission adm
WHERE  adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '2014-01-01' AND adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '2014-12-31' AND
       adm.adm_PriorSurgery = 'Yes' AND
       adm.adm_Consultant <> ''
GROUP BY adm_Consultant;
```

Comment: You didn't tell me him the actual reason why his query didn't work :)

Comment: The error message was too vague to know the exact reason.