# aggregate sql with a where clause and Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry, this ties into my previous question. [`https://stackoverflow.com/q/29523379/2240163`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29523379/2240163)

But I suppose I have to ask a new question.

```
SELECT adm.adm_Consultant, surg.Type AS 'Surgery Type', surg.srg_Details AS 'Procedure', count(surg.srg_Details) as SurgeryNum
FROM Admission adm
JOIN Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_admID = adm.adm_ID
JOIN Surgery surg ON surg.srg_lnkID = lnk.lnk_ID
WHERE  adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '2014-01-01' AND adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '2014-12-31'
AND adm.adm_PriorSurgery = 'Yes'
AND adm.adm_Consultant <> ''
GROUP BY surg.srg_Details
```

Why does it fail, and can you even do a aggregate query like this?

This works, but I want to try and get a count on the `Procedure`'s

```
SELECT adm.adm_Consultant, surg.Type AS 'Surgery Type', surg.srg_Details AS 'Procedure'
FROM Admission adm
JOIN Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_admID = adm.adm_ID
JOIN Surgery surg ON surg.srg_lnkID = lnk.lnk_ID
WHERE  adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '2014-01-01' AND adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '2014-12-31'
AND adm.adm_PriorSurgery = 'Yes'
AND adm.adm_Consultant <> ''
ORDER BY surg.srg_Details
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add all columns from `SELECT` clause to `GROUP BY` clause:

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a **GROUP BY** clause cannot refer
>   to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the
>   **GROUP BY** clause.

You can read [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).

```
SELECT adm.adm_Consultant, surg.Type AS 'Surgery Type', surg.srg_Details AS 'Procedure', count(surg.srg_Details) as SurgeryNum
FROM Admission adm
JOIN Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_admID = adm.adm_ID
JOIN Surgery surg ON surg.srg_lnkID = lnk.lnk_ID
WHERE  adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '2014-01-01' AND adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '2014-12-31'
AND adm.adm_PriorSurgery = 'Yes'
AND adm.adm_Consultant <> ''
GROUP BY adm.adm_Consultant, surg.Type, surg.srg_Details
```

Comment: That worked. But can you explain the reason why maybe please. Thanks @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas

Comment: @morne Updated my answer with explaination and link to documentation.